# Compile TensorFlow with SSE4.2 and AVX fails with bazel

Tags: tensorflow, sse, bazel, avx, msys

I have installed Tensorflow Bazel and MSYS and I tried to make Tensorflow compile to support **CPU extensions, such as SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AVX, AVX2, FMA** using the following command from Win 10 command prompt:

```
  bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=- 
  mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.2 --config=cuda -k 
 //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

But it is failing with the error below:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 
--copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.2 --config=cuda - 
 k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
 Bazel on Windows requires bash.exe and other Unix tools, but we 
could not find them.
If you do not have them installed, the easiest is to install 
 MSYS2 from
 http://repo.msys2.org/distrib/msys2-x86_64-latest.exe
 or git-on-Windows from
 https://git-scm.com/download/win

If you already have bash.exe installed but Bazel cannot find 
it,
set BAZEL_SH environment variable to its location:
set BAZEL_SH=c:\path\to\bash.exe
[bazel INFO src/main/cpp/blaze_util_windows.cc:1231] Cannot 
 open 
 HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Git_is1
 [bazel ERROR src/main/cpp/blaze_util_windows.cc:1303] bash.exe 
 not found on PATH
 [bazel INFO src/main/cpp/blaze_util_windows.cc:1328] BAZEL_SH 
 detection took 0 msec, found
```

MSYS is running normally as seen below:

```
ippok@DESKTOP-4QMUDH4 MSYS ~
$
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to run the command `bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=- 
  mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.2 --config=cuda -k 
 //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` _in_ MSYS ?

Comment: Bazel works fine from `cmd.exe`, no need to run from MSYS.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you what to do: set the `BAZEL_SH` envvar to the path of bash.exe.

To set it for the current cmd.exe session, use:

```
set BAZEL_SH=c:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe
```

To set it for all *future* cmd.exe sessions (not this one):

```
setx BAZEL_SH "c:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe"
```

If you installed MSYS in a different location, then change these commands accordingly.